# JQuery code taking too much time to load

Tags: jquery, html, web, jquery-click-event

I have written a jquery code for simple click events, however I have not used loops.
Is that why the click events for but_4 and but_3 are taking a lot of time to respond?
Following is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.modulename').animate({left:'15px',opacity:'1'},2000,function(){
      $('.eventone,.rule_1,.faq_1,.cont_1,.spons_1').animate({right:'45px',opacity:'1'},1000,function(){
             $('.eventtwo,.rule_2,.faq_2,.cont_2,.spons_2').animate({left:'10px',opacity:'1'},1000,function(){
            $('.eventthree,.rule_3,.faq_3,.cont_3,.spons_3').animate({right:'45px',opacity:'1'},1000,function(){
                $('.eventfour,.rule_4,.faq_4,.cont_4,.spons_4').animate({left:'10px',opacity:'1'},1000);
            });
        });
    });
});

    var $open = null;
$('.but1_1').click(function(){
    if($open != null)
        $open.slideToggle();
    $('.rule_1').slideToggle();
    $open = $('.rule_1');
});
$('.but1_2').click(function(){
    if($open != null)
        $open.slideToggle();
    $('.faq_1').slideToggle();
    $open = $('.faq_1');
});
$('.but1_3').click(function(){
    if($open != null)
        $open.slideToggle();
    $('.cont_1').slideToggle();
    $open = $('.cont_1');
});
$('.but1_4').click(function(){
    if($open != null)
        $open.slideToggle();
    $('.spons_1').slideToggle();
    $open = $('.spons_1');
});

$('.but2_1').click(function(){
    if($open != null)
        $open.slideToggle();
    $('.rule_2').slideToggle();
    $open = $('.rule_2');
});
$('.but2_2').click(function(){
    if($open != null)
        $open.slideToggle();
    $('.faq_2').slideToggle();
    $open = $('.faq_2');
});
$('.but2_3').click(function(){
    if($open != null)
        $open.slideToggle();
    $('.cont_2').slideToggle();
    $open = $('.cont_2');
});
$('.but2_4').click(function(){
    if($open != null)
        $open.slideToggle();
    $('.spons_2').slideToggle();
    $open = $('.spons_2');
});

$('.but3_1').click(function(){
    if($open != null)
        $open.slideToggle();
    $('.rule_3').slideToggle();
    $open = $('.rule_3');
});
$('.but3_2').click(function(){
    if($open != null)
        $open.slideToggle();
    $('.faq_3').slideToggle();
    $open = $('.faq_3');
});
$('.but3_3').click(function(){
    if($open != null)
        $open.slideToggle();
    $('.cont_3').slideToggle();
    $open = $('.cont_3');
});
$('.but3_4').click(function(){
    if($open != null)
        $open.slideToggle();
    $('.spons_3').slideToggle();
    $open = $('.spons_3');
});

$('.but4_1').click(function(){
    if($open != null)
        $open.slideToggle();
    $('.rule_4').slideToggle();
    $open = $('.rule_4');
});
$('.but4_2').click(function(){
    if($open != null)
        $open.slideToggle();
    $('.faq_4').slideToggle();
    $open = $('.faq_4');
});
$('.but4_3').click(function(){
    if($open != null)
        $open.slideToggle();
    $('.cont_4').slideToggle();
    $open = $('.cont_4');
});
$('.but4_4').click(function(){
    if($open != null)
        $open.slideToggle();
    $('.spons_4').slideToggle();
    $open = $('.spons_4');
});
});
```

Please can anyone suggest a better way to write this code so that it responds quickly?

Comment: can you made a jsfiddle so we can test it ? also, try to make stop().animate(...) instead of .animate(), to make sure animations does not queues.

Comment: The animate() functions were causing the problem. I hard coded the left margins of the but* divs. Now its working properly.

Answer (score 0):

add else statement in all your functions that may help you

```
$('.but3_1').click(function(){
if($open != null)
 {
    $open.slideToggle();
 }
 else
 {
    $('.rule_3').slideToggle();
    $open = $('.rule_3');
 }
});
```